# Как удалить класс со стилями

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, frontend

Здравствуйте!
Есть задача: на div висят 2 класса со стилями, например: .style1 и style2.
При определенном разрешении .style2 мне не нужен(хочу вернуть дефолтные свойства div, которые я переопределил в .style2).
Знаю как это сделать на js, есть ли более элегантное решение?

Comment: есть, а какой контекст у задачи? в какой момент нужно убрать `style2`?

Comment: Спасибо, уже решил проблему, решение Victor Khovanskiy мне подошло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалить не получится, но можно просто указать аттрибуты только для определенного разрешения. Например:

```
<div class="style1 style2">...</div>
```

и

```
.style1 { color: red; }
@media screen and (device-width: 1280px) {
   style2 { color: green; }
}
```